# Boost beast send json with byte array to client throw websocket

Tags: c++, json, boost, websocket, beast

I have file which is converted from byte array to string

```
processResultJson.append(reinterpret_cast<const char *const>(im->bits), sizeof(im->bits));
processResultJson.append(reinterpret_cast<const char *const>(im->bits), im_res->bmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage);

docData.put("Image1", processResultJson);}
boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(m_stream, SRegulaDR::docData);
resultString = m_stream.str();

size_t n = net::buffer_copy(buffer_.prepare(resultString.size()), net::buffer(resultString));        buffer_.commit(n);
```

in this situation i get error_code=2 - End of file
and then error_code=995 I/O operation...

How i can send JSON with byte array witch converted to string
Thanks!!!

Comment: In **what** situation do you get end-of-file? There's no reading code in sight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Property Tree as if it's a JSON library. It has well known limitations: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.json_parser

Note especially the limitationssurrounding arrays.

Next up, you didn't write an array to begin with, instead writing a string. But since it's binary data, it may be a valid JSON string, and this could be a source of error.

Also, you probably don't need to copy the whole JSON **again** to put it in a buffer. Instead, `boost::asio::buffer(resultString)` will work (as long as you make sure that the lifetime of `resultString` is enough, like with `buffer_`).

Just testing a little does suggest that characters are being escaped correctly by `write_json`:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rvY48T)**

```
#define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::string_literals;

struct Im { std::array<std::uint64_t, 10> bits; };

int main()
{
    auto im = std::make_unique<Im>(
            Im { 0b0010'1100'1010'0010'0111'1100'0010 });

    std::string_view bitmsg(
        reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&im->bits),
        sizeof(im->bits));

    auto processResultJson = "some binary data: \0 \x10 \xef αβγδ\n"s;
    processResultJson += bitmsg;

    boost::property_tree::ptree docData; 
    docData.put("Image1", processResultJson);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(oss, docData);

    std::cout << oss.str();
}
```

Prints

> `{ "Image1": "some binary data: \u0000 \u0010 αβγδ\nu0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000" }`

Json lint reports it as valid JSON (for what it's worth)

However, consider making doubly sure by

- using base64 encoding to encode binary data
- using Boost JSON or another proper JSON library

### Demo With Boost JSON

1.75.0 introduced a proper JSON library. Let's celebrate.

The straightforward translation is: https://godbolt.org/z/es9jGc

```
json::object docData;
docData["Image1"] = processResultJson;

std::string resultString = json::serialize(docData);
```

However, you can now easily use strong-typed, proper arrays: https://godbolt.org/z/K9c6bc

```
json::object docData;
docData["Image1"] = json::array(im->bits.begin(), im->bits.end());
```

Printing

```
{"Image1":[46802882,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

Or you can, in fact, use default conversions with `value_from`: :

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4dorTq)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for header-only
namespace json = boost::json;

struct Im { std::array<std::uint64_t, 10> bits; };

int main()
{
    auto im = std::make_unique<Im>(
            Im { 0b0010'1100'1010'0010'0111'1100'0010, /*...*/ });

    std::cout << json::object{ {"Image1", json::value_from(im->bits) } };
}
```

Prints

```
{"Image1":[46802882,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

Comment: I try using boost json and now get another problem. If I include<boost/json/src.hpp> I get LNK2005 errors

Comment: I only add #include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> and only implement static class member as boost::json::object and get LNK2005 errors

Comment: You can link it or include the source header as well (like I did on computer explorer)

Comment: Hi sehe. I put my question on this link more detailed with codes can you help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66298798/why-i-get-lnk2005-errors-on-using-boost-json